# Is there a generating function for any finite sequence of random numbers?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

**hypothesis: for any finite sequence of random positive integers exists a generating function.**

If the hypothesis is true, is there a structured way of finding a generating function for a finite sequence of random positive integers?

---

Here is what I understand from the past 2 days of reading:

A generating function for Fibonacci numbers - eventhough it doesn't have much to do with my question - is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1− (x + x ^ 2)}
\end{eqnarray*}
where:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1− (x + x ^ 2)} =1 + x + 2  x ^ 2 + 3  x ^ 3 + 5  x ^ 4 + 8  x ^ 5+ \cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}
The coefficients are Fibonacci numbers, i.e. the sequence {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21, ...}.

**But if I have a finite sequence of random numbers, for example {4,5,0,9,1,5}
Is there a method of finding its generating function?**

Comment: Cf. finite impulse response (FIR) filter.

Comment: Generating functions are defined for *infinite* sequences. Should we assume that your finite sequence continues with "0,0,0,..."? Or should we assume that there are further elements after the ones you have specified but they are unknown?

Comment: I'd recommend **saying *arbitrary* instead of *random*** if you don't talk about random processes at all. And if you do really mean random processes, be precise about distributions. Often people will say that a (perfect) die is "random", but a faked die with 30%-70% chances for head-tail is *not* random -- which is wrong! It's no longer uniformly random, that's true.

Comment: Reply to @FedericoPoloni: I always thought of a finite series as an infinite series that continues with "0,0,0,..." (as it relates to my problem). Would that still be possible if I gave you this information?

Comment: Yes, @RobPratt's answer below is correct assuming that your (finite) sequence is padded with zeros. That is a reasonable convention in this context.

Comment: @ComFreek -- good point about arbitrary, I'll try to remember that usage yourself (my wife was a math major, btw)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a sequence with finitely many nonzero values, the corresponding generating function is just a polynomial.  Your example has generating function $4+5x+9x^3+x^4+5x^5$.

Comment: Why is there a non-zero constraint? If the whole finite sequence is just zeros, wouldn't that be a constant function? Constant functions are polynomials. What's your perspective on this?

Comment: @Galen: It's the opposite of infinitely many nonzero values. The zero polynomial is fine, it has **no** nonzero terms, and that's finitely many.

Comment: I follow that. Thanks!